# Comparison of sums based on the comparison of weighted averages.

Tags: number-theory, summation, average

Suppose $w_i>0$ are normalized weights, and $\sum_{i}^{n}w_i x_i>\sum_{i}^{n}w_i y_i > \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}^{n} y_i$. Does this imply the following:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i>\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i$$.

**This is my trial**. Suppose $w_n = \sup\{w_1,...,w_n\}$. Then,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_n x_i=w_n\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i>\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i x_i>\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i y_i>\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i.$$

Because all weights are strictly positive and normalized between 0 and 1, then the following should hold:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i>w_n\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i>\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i.$$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: The $1/n$ in the assumption is missing where you apply it.

Comment: Yes, you are right!. How can I get rid of $\frac{1}{n}$ there?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.

Take $n=2$, $x_1=1$, $x_2=10$, $y_1=3$, $y_2=9$, $w_1=0.1$ and $w_2=0.9$.

Then $ \displaystyle \sum_{i}^{n}w_i x_i = 9.1$ ; $ \displaystyle \sum_{i}^{n}w_i y_i = 8.4$ ; and $\dfrac{1}{n}  \displaystyle \sum_{i}^{n} y_i = 6$, so one has
$$ \displaystyle \sum_{i}^{n}w_i x_i  >  \sum_{i}^{n}w_i y_i > \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i}^{n} y_i $$

but $\displaystyle \sum_{i}^{n} x_i =11$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{i}^{n} y_i =12$.

Comment: Can you help me with some conditions under which the proposition will hold true?

Comment: Essentially you're asking " If $ \sum w_i a_i > 0$, is $ \sum a_i > 0$", with $a_i = x_i - y_i$. So, if you underweight the largest elements, then the claim will be true. (The example here overweights the largest elements)